# Display data from list with index using angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

How to display data in HTML from a list without using `*ngFor`
for example like This `list[5].name`

I tried this :

```
PostList[5].{{def}}

{{PostList[5].def}}
```

Comment: do you mean `*ngFor`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use ngFor or ngRepeat?

Comment: They were basically asking, how can you retrieve an object in an array given a specific index in html. They are avoiding having to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `{{PostList[5].def}}` works.

Assuming you have your component initializing a simple list with an `Object`

```
export class AppComponent  {
  list = new Array<{name: string}>();

  constructor() {
    this.list[0] = {"name": "Martin"}
    this.list[1] = {"name": "Emma"}
    this.list[2] = {"name": "Daisy"}
  }
}
```

and if you want to get `Emma`, your view will therefore be.

```
<p>
  {{list[1].name}}
</p>

//Output Emma
```

**Update**
I would like to add that, if for instance the `list` doesnt have a certain index e.g index greater than 2, or the value is null. You can use the `?` operator in html to be safe.

Therefore `{{list[3]?.name}}` wont crash your app, even though the output is null.

Answer (score 0):

`{{PostList[5].def}}` should work if you have `this.PostList` variable in your component (and it is an array which 6th element is an object with def)